# Modifying contents of a binary file in Java

Tags: java, java-io

I'm writing a program in Java that I plan to use for modding a certain video game by modifying the game's binary data. It's stored in a .dat file that simply contains bytes of game data.  What I have been working with is `FileInputStream` to read in the file and `FileOutputStream` to modify the contents. However, as far as I am aware `FileOutputStream` is only capable of modifying the end of the file, not contents in the middle.

What I want to be able to do the following:

If this is a binary file provided:

```
06 B4 45 18 A7 DD
```

I would want to be able to, for instance, modify the byte at position n=3 and change it to value v=FF.

resulting in:

```
06 B4 45 FF A7 DD
```

I'd like to write this data back to the file then.

What would be the best way of tackling this? Right now, the only way I could see `FileOutputStream` working is if I actually took the original file, and reconstructed it from start to finish but swapping out the new values in the process. However, that seems really inefficient considering the files I plan to modify contain roughly 20,000 bytes each.

I feel like there has to be an easier way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ththere is no such thing as a hex file. This is a binary file. He's is just a representation for display.

Comment: `FileOutputStream` *can* 'append' to an existing file at the end, or replace it entirely from the beginning. Yes, you would need to read and rewrite the whole thing, so @Eggen's answer `RandomAccessFile` is better. But 20,000 bytes could be a concern 40 years ago; on today's machines it's unnoticeable. The JVM that runs your Java program is typically 20,000,000 to 50,000,000 bytes minimum and often 10 times that or more.

Answer (score 3):

You need a [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). That would be sufficient, but you may for more performance use a `getChannel()` and a `ByteBuffer`.

As the name says a RandomAccessFile allows positioning anywhere, and read and write.

```
try (RandomAccessFile fh = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw")) {
    fh.seek(3L);
    int old = fh.read(); // 0x18
    fh.seek(3L);
    fh.write(0xBB);
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, that does exactly what I want. Thanks!